# Order rows by score calculated in the select query in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, expression, sql-order-by

I have a table in an sqlite3 database with some columns in it that may be null.

I want to create a select query that is ordered by a calculated score so that the score is an integer corresponding to how many of the columns are null for each row. My naive approach (which is not valid) looks like this:

```
select id,
case when column_1 is null then 0 else 1 end as score_part_1,
case when column_2 is null then 0 else 1 end as score_part_2,
case when column_3 is null then 0 else 1 end as score_part_3,
(score_part_1 + score_part_2 + score_part_3) as score,
from my_table
where score < 3
order by score desc;
```

Is this possible? What would be the best way to do it from clarity and performance perspective?

Comment: No.  You need to use a CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite evaluates Boolean expressions like:

```
column_1 is null
```

as `0` (False) or `1` (True).
So you can do it like this:

```
select * from mytable 
order by 
  (column_1 is not null) +
  (column_2 is not null) +
  (column_3 is not null) desc
```

If you want to include the result of the sum as a column, use a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
      (column_1 is not null) +
      (column_2 is not null) +
      (column_3 is not null) score  
  from mytable
)
select * from cte
where score < 3
order by score desc
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading this I decided to try anyway and it turns out we don't need the CTE! I posted a separate answer.

Comment: @LennartRolland it's true that you don't need the CTE because SQLite allows the use of derived columns in the WHERE clause (unlike all other rdbms), but this is not a standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `CASE` expressions to get the overall score and also filter or order by like that.

```
SELECT id,
       CASE
         WHEN column_1 IS NULL THEN
           0
         ELSE
           1 
       END score_part_1,
       CASE
         WHEN column_2 IS NULL THEN
           0
         ELSE
           1 
       END score_part_2,
       CASE
         WHEN column_3 IS NULL THEN
           0
         ELSE
           1 
       END score_part_3,
       CASE
         WHEN column_1 IS NULL THEN
           0
         ELSE
           1 
       END score_part_1
       +
       CASE
         WHEN column_2 IS NULL THEN
           0
         ELSE
           1 
       END score_part_2
       +
       CASE
         WHEN column_3 IS NULL THEN
           0
         ELSE
           1 
       END score
       FROM my_table
       WHERE CASE
               WHEN column_1 IS NULL THEN
                 0
               ELSE
                 1 
             END score_part_1
             +
             CASE
               WHEN column_2 IS NULL THEN
                 0
               ELSE
                 1 
             END score_part_2
             +
             CASE
               WHEN column_3 IS NULL THEN
                 0
               ELSE
                 1 
             END
             < 3
       ORDER BY CASE
                  WHEN column_1 IS NULL THEN
                    0
                  ELSE
                    1 
                END score_part_1
                +
                CASE
                  WHEN column_2 IS NULL THEN
                    0
                  ELSE
                    1 
                END score_part_2
                +
                CASE
                  WHEN column_3 IS NULL THEN
                    0
                  ELSE
                    1 
                END DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out this can be done much simpler (thankfully).

Answer (score 0):

It seems today we all learned something!

I tested the following query on `SQLite 3.29.0` under `Ubuntu 19.04 AMD64`:

```
select id,
( (column_1 is not null)
+ (column_2 is not null)
+ (column_3 is not null) ) as score
from my_table
where score < 3
order by score desc;
```

And it worked as expected.